# Node Express Send File Writing Partial HTML File

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redhat

We have a problem where the res.sendFile() method in Node Express app is sending partial html files. We are running the node app on Red Hat

This problem starts to appear after running the process for some hours and after restart everything starts working absolutely fine.

```
var page = /usr/somefile.html;

res.sendFile(page,options,function (err) {
          if (err) {
            logger.error("Error while sending file " +err);
            res.status(err.status).end();
          }
          else {
            logger.info('Sent:', page);
          }
        });
```

Comment: sounds like a memory leak

Comment: Is there a way I can debug and find the issue on a node express app. We tried to see the memory and cpu usage for the node process and everything seems proper. Even the file descriptors are below the soft and hard limit.